# If statement using templatetag

Tags: django, django-templates

How would I do the following in django:

```
{% if value|truncatewords > 10 %} print this {% endif %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you comparing a string to an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting you want to count the words in a string. Try this one:

```
{% if value|wordcount > 10 %} print this {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an incorrect use of the [`truncatewords`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) filter. You must specify the number of words you wish to truncate after:

```
{{ value|truncatewords:10 }}
```